# Checkboxes disappear when I added a Fieldset

Tags: html, xhtml

I have this code I'm working on and when I added the fieldset to my checkboxes it just disappeared.  Before I added the fieldset the checkboxes showed up just fine along with the radio buttons.  Thanks in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html>
<LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="davidwalker.css" TYPE="text/css">
<head><title>Contact Us!</title></head>
<form>
Name:  <input type="text" name="custname" /><br />
Email:  <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
Questions/Comments/Concerns:  <textarea name="comments" rows="10" cols="30"></textarea><br />
Please select your category:    <select name="category">
                                <option value="appdev">Application Development</option>
                                <option value="hardware">Hardware Question</option>
                                <option value="general">General Question</option>
                                </select><br />
<FIELDSET>
    <LEGEND ACCESSKEY=O>Please select your OS:</LEGEND>
    <LABEL ACCESSKEY=1><input type="radio" name="OS" value="WinXP" />Windows XP</LABEL><br />
    <LABEL ACCESSKEY=2><input type="radio" name="OS" value="Mac" />Mac</LABEL><br />
    <LABEL ACCESSKEY=3><input type="radio" name="OS" value="Linux" />Linux</LABEL><br />
    <LABEL ACCESSKEY=4><input type="radio" name="OS" value="Free" />FreeBSD</LABEL><br />
    <LABEL ACCESSKEY=5><input type="radio" name="OS" value="other" />Other</LABEL><br />
</FIELDSET>
<FIELDSET>
    <LEGEND ACCESSKEY=D>Please select your devices:</LEGEND>  
    <LABEL ACCESSKEY=6<input type="checkbox" name="device" value="PC" />PC</LABEL><br />
    <LABEL ACCESSKEY=7<input type="checkbox" name="device" value="Mac" />Mac</LABEL><br />
    <LABEL ACCESSKEY=8<input type="checkbox" name="device" value="Tablet">Tablet</LABEL><br />
    <LABEL ACCESSKEY=9<input type="checkbox" name="device" value="SmartPhone">SmartPhone</LABEL><br />
</FIELDSET>


<html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not closing the begin tags in the second fieldset...

```
<LABEL ACCESSKEY=6<input type="checkbox" name="device" value="PC" />
```

notice: the missing ">" after ACCESSKEY=6

```
 <LABEL ACCESSKEY=6><input type="checkbox" name="device" value="PC" />
```

I think that should solve your problem :-)

Comment: Thanks! small things overlooked!

Answer (score 1):

I notice that in the second fieldset, for Tablet and SmartPhone you don't have the closing `/` after the input elements.  Please see if that helps.

i.e. change:

```
<LABEL ACCESSKEY=8<input type="checkbox" name="device" value="Tablet">Tablet</LABEL><br />
<LABEL ACCESSKEY=9<input type="checkbox" name="device" value="SmartPhone">SmartPhone</LABEL><br />
```

to

```
<LABEL ACCESSKEY=8<input type="checkbox" name="device" value="Tablet"/>Tablet</LABEL><br />
<LABEL ACCESSKEY=9<input type="checkbox" name="device" value="SmartPhone"/>SmartPhone</LABEL><br />
```

Comment: I doubt there is any case in which a missing closing slash like that would make any problem. Browsers have been written to specifically ignore exactly that error.

Comment: Read [Sending XHTML as text/html Considered Harmful](http://hixie.ch/advocacy/xhtml); it explains why browsers treat "XHTML" as tag soup.